# Crash in mlr3learners.lightgbm when load dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, mlr3

I am using lightgbm in a mlr3 and wrangle Data  uses functions from the dplyr.

The R session in RStudio crashes when i load library(dplyr).

```
library(dplyr) # crash if load 
library(mlr3)
library(mlr3learners.lightgbm)
task = mlr3::tsk("iris")
learner = mlr3::lrn("classif.lightgbm", objective = "multiclass")

learner$param_set$values = mlr3misc::insert_named(
  learner$param_set$values,
  list(
    "early_stopping_round" = 10,
    "learning_rate" = 0.1,
    "seed" = 17L,
    "metric" = "multi_logloss",
    "num_iterations" = 100,
    "num_class" = 3
  )
)

learner$train(task, row_ids = 1:120)
predictions = learner$predict(task, row_ids = 121:150)
```

Comment: Is there an error message? I'm getting a regular error if I take the lightgbm from the mlr3extralearners package (https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3extralearners).

Comment: if i run step by step sequentially like above it get error "R session Aborted". If I load the lightgbm package in before load dplyr, I don't get the error.

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue on Windows specifically ([microsoft/LightGBM#4464](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/4464)), where the order of package loading can lead `{lightgbm}` to produce crashes. This issue is known to affect versions 3.0.0 to 3.2.1, and will be fixed in a future release.

If you are on Windows and installed the package from CRAN with `install.packages("lightgbm")`, use `library(lightgbm)` before loading any other packages in your R session, and you will not see crashes.

Alternatively, you can install a version of `{lightgbm}` which does not suffer from this issue with any of the following approaches

1. Use a macOS or Linux system if one is available to you.
2. Clone https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM, apply the changes from https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/pull/4496, and then compile the package from source.

```sh
git submodule init
git submodule update --recursive
sh build-cran-package.sh
R CMD INSTALL lightgbm_*.tar.gz
```

3. Clone https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM and install the package using `CMake` and Visual Studio compilers.

```sh
git submodule init
git submodule update --recursive
Rscript build_r.R
```

Comment: I load lightgbm before other packages, it's still crashed.